# Why is there extra space in left justified longtable cell when creating custom function

Tags: longtable, scrlttr2, fp

I'm using the `longtable` and `fp` packages to create an invoice in the `scrlttr2` document. I have used the `\entry` custom command to allow for creating running totals, compute the tax, and obtain a grand total. The problem is that in the table body, all of the first cells filled by the `\entry` command have excess white space before them. This problem doesn't happen in any other cell! I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

I have tried forcing the contents left by using `\multicolumn` within the definition of `\entry`, but LaTeX throws an error. Similarly I have tried `\begin{flushleft} ... \end{flushleft}`, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Find below a MWE.

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt, a4]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut after hline
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.0ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut before hline

%%Longtable \entry and fp commands
\FPset{itemTotal}{0}
\FPset{vat}{0.17}
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
    \FPeval{itemTotal}{itemTotal+#5}% Add to each itemTotal
    \FPmul{\tax}{\vat}{\itemTotal}
    \FPadd{\grandTotal}{\tax}{\itemTotal}
    \xdef\grandTotal{\grandTotal}
    \xdef\tax{\tax}
    \xdef\itemTotal{\itemTotal}% Make definition \global
#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5% Set entry
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{%
            Bill To:\\
            Someone\\
            Some House\\
            Somewhere Ville
        }
    \KOMAoptions{parskip=yes}
    \opening{\null}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{|llrrr|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Unit Price} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Item Total}\T\B\\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \entry{10/03/2016}{Something I did}{10/hour}{6}{60.00}\T\\
            \entry{12/03/2016}{Something I claim I did}{50/hour}{5}{250.00}\B\\
            \hline\hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|r}{Subtotal}&\FPround{\itemTotal}{\itemTotal}{2}\itemTotal\T\\*
            \multicolumn{4}{|r}{VAT 17.0\%}&\FPround{\tax}{\tax}{2}\tax\\*[5pt]
            \multicolumn{4}{|r}{\textbf{Grand Total}}&\FPround{\grandTotal}{\grandTotal}{2}\grandTotal\B\\*
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}

    \closing{\null}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of missing `%` at the end. That are all spaces otherwise

```
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
    \FPeval{itemTotal}{itemTotal+#5}% Add to each itemTotal
    \FPmul{\tax}{\vat}{\itemTotal}%
    \FPadd{\grandTotal}{\tax}{\itemTotal}%
    \xdef\grandTotal{\grandTotal}%
    \xdef\tax{\tax}%
    \xdef\itemTotal{\itemTotal}% Make definition \global
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5% Set entry
}
```